# Combining data in several rows into one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am having difficulty combining (merging) rows in SQL: I am looking for a row that contains

CLIENTID, TOTAL COUNTS AT ALL LEVELS, LEVEL COUNTs (at each level).

Here is an example:

```
ClientID    Total Counts    Level1  Level2  Level3
1234566     12              9        3      0
```

Here is the code I have, and I've twisted and turned it but it always comes up short: it gives me nulls at every level except for the one. But I want data all combined into one row.  Thank you very much in advance

```
            SELECT u.clientID AS CLIENTID_SHORT, 
            CASE WHEN LEVEL='1' THEN COUNT(*) END AS Level1,
            CASE WHEN LEVEL='2' THEN COUNT(*) END AS Level2,
            CASE WHEN LEVEL='3' THEN COUNT(*) END AS Level3,
            CASE WHEN LEVEL='4' THEN COUNT(*) END AS Level4,
            CASE WHEN LEVEL='5' THEN COUNT(*) END AS Level5
            FROM CLIENTPROFILE u
            GROUP BY u.ClientID, u.LEVEL
            ORDER BY CLIENTID_SHORT
```

Comment: Can you post some Sample data to go with your query please? [How to post a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `count` on top of `case` statement

```
SELECT u.clientID AS CLIENTID_SHORT,
       Count(*) AS TotalLevelCount,
       Count(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Level1,
       Count(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Level2,
       Count(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Level3,
       Count(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 4 THEN 1 END) AS Level4,
       Count(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 5 THEN 1 END) AS Level5
FROM   CLIENTPROFILE u
WHERE  LEVEL >= 1
       AND Level <= 5
GROUP  BY u.ClientID
ORDER  BY CLIENTID_SHORT
```

**Note :** You don't have to use single quotes while checking against integer columns.

Comment: You shouldn't be grouping by `u.Level`

Comment: @Lamak makes me feel silly for even asking this Q. But I didn't know you could do this. Just another silly question, why shouldn't we group by Level? I thought we should... else, it'd given an error that Level isn't part of aggregate function

Comment: @LearnByReading but `LEVEL` **is** inside an aggregation function. You can try the previous query and see the effect it would have in your results. Basically you wouldn't have a single row per `clientId`, but one per combination of `clientID - LEVEL`

Comment: @LearnByReading - You can use `Count(*)` instead

Comment: @Pரதீப் that's true. However, I thought that may include results that are out of scope (for instance Level = 6 or higher.

Comment: @LearnByReading - I have added `where` clause ;) so that won't happen. You just need the level count of 1 to 5 so its better to add `where` filter clause for optimal performance.